# Conditional Formatting using multiple parameters in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[image]

In the supplied picture I am attempting to create a conditional format. What I want to do is If the F column contains "A", "B", or "C" then the dates in the H column need to be compared to the three dates in the M column. However, each one of those dates correspond with the letters in column K. So the "A" cycle date begins 7/1/2020-6/30/2021. For example, F2 is a letter "C", the last review was done on 12/1/21, and the next cycle date begins on 7/1/2022. So it's time for F2's information to be reviewed again since the last time it was reviewed was prior to the date listed in M5. Any suggestions on how to make this work? I hope it all made sense.

I have tried variations of IF, AND, and DATE formatting, and while I did get close with one formula (`=H2<$M$3:$M$5`) it still did not yield the results I was wanting. The formula even highlighted empty cells which are also not what I want. I have been researching for the last two days.

Comment: `=AND(INDEX(K:K,MATCH(H2,M:M))<>F2,F2<>"")`  One note, you will need the data in the lookup range to be sorted on the date in column M for this to work

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the formula i have used in conditional formatting

```
=N(ISNA(AND(INDEX($K$3:$K$5,MATCH(1,(H2>=$M$3:$M$5)*(H2<=$N$3:$N$5),0))=F2,F2<>"")))=0
```

[image]

Comment: Getting closer however in this situation all of the letters but C4 should be highlighted because the last review for them was prior to the dates listed in M3-M5.